# How would I implement multithreading in this situation? Is it possible?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, backgroundworker

I have a form with a listview in it that the user can add tasks too. Then the user can click a button then the application goes through each task in the listview 1 by 1 an executes it.

These tasks are more like instructions that actually complete tasks.I do this by having a class with a loop in it that goes through each item and it then completes a task I set for each item(instruction). In order to start the parsing I have a button on a form that calls that function. IE: RunTask(listview1, 1) - basically all this does it starts the loop I have in my class , with a specified listview and which item to start on.

Everything works perfect except the screen locks up, so I cannot implement a stop feature to stop the application from parsing these listview items. I just don't understand how I can implement this without crossthreading, since the thread that I would like to run seperate will always access this listview. It is not feasable to redesign the program to get rid of the listview. I tried application.doevents although it caused way too man bugs. I have been researching for days on how to fix this but I have NO idea. Hopefully someone cans hed some light.

Also I had already added a background worker to solve the issue, although I had to obviously set checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls = false and I know this isn't smart.

Comment: Separate the data from the view.  No reason that you need a ListView to store the data, it was not designed to be a collection object.

Comment: The only thing is that I store information in the listview items tag as well. Also I have it setup so I can pause it, by doing this when the pause button is clicked, it selects the current item. Then when the play button is hit again it checks if item is selected, and if it is it starts from that item. It also has a couple other features that use the listview directly, that I don't think would be possible with a standard List. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this. Take you list view and turn it into a set of values that aren't UI related. Like this:

```
        string[] values =
            this
                .listView1
                .Items
                .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                .Select(x => x.Text)
                .ToArray();
```

Then you can use the parallel task library to run your task in the background:

```
        var tokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = tokenSource.Token;

        var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory
                .StartNew(() => RunTasks(values, 1), token);
```

If you need to cancel the task you can do this:

```
        tokenSource.Cancel();
```

But to handle UI updates when the task is finished do this:

```
        task.ContinueWith(r =>
        {
            /* When compete code */
        });
```

Make sure that you invoke the UI updates so that they go on the UI thread.

My apologies that I didn't write this in VB.NET. My VB is getting rusty.

Comment: So does this basically turn my listview into a list? If so then I added a comment above about my use  of the listview, what would I do in this situation. I really appreciate your help. I don't know c# although I am sure I can use a converter to convert it easily.

Comment: So here's the trick then. Make a new class called `ListViewData`. Change the reference to your list view (in your task processing code only) to be an instance of this new class. You'll now get errors One by one add child-classes/methods/properties that are errors to the `ListViewData` class until the errors go away. You now have separated out the UI `ListView` class into a non-UI `ListViewData` class. This kind of refactoring should become quite easy after a while. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you though this is what I have done.